# Using Joomla CMS with Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, joomla

I currently have a Java Servlet backend Tomcat server running,
and I want to create the front-end(webpage) with a good CMS

and make a call to my java Servlet I understand that Joomla is a php base content-management system so is there a way that I can get it work such as using a REST service, or using PHP/JAVA Bridge or even install xampp would help ?

Or is Java base CMS the only CMS Tomcat server will be able to run?

Comment: You may know Joomla is PHP based. So you won't be able to run in on your Tomcat server.

Comment: Sorry for that I didnt realized the PHP based cms will not run on my Tomcat server, and thank you for replying me this fast. So in this case do you have any suggestions to where I show go from here ?  as suppose a better cms that runs on a java base, im looking for a cms that is greatly scalable, and designed for multi user login ?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look for Java based CMS. There are so many options. 
dotCMS may be a good pick, but it depends. So take a look and 
see what meets your requirements. 
[Java based CMS list](http://java.dzone.com/articles/top-21-java-based-content)